# How to run an Asyncio task without awaiting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I need to call a task periodically but (a)waiting times are almost more than the period.

In the following code, How can I run `do_something()` task without need to `await` for the result?

```
 import asyncio
 import time
 from random import randint

 period = 1  # Second


 def get_epoch_ms():
     return int(time.time() * 1000.0)


 async def do_something(name):
     print("Start  :", name, get_epoch_ms())
     try:
         # Do something which may takes more than 1 secs.
         slp = randint(1, 5)
         print("Sleep  :", name, get_epoch_ms(), slp)
         await asyncio.sleep(slp)
     except Exception as e:
         print("Error  :", e)

     print("Finish :", name, get_epoch_ms())


 async def main():
     i = 0
     while True:
         i += 1
         # Todo : this line should be change
         await do_something('T' + str(i))
         await asyncio.sleep(period)


 asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: The time you wait for the result cannot really be shorter than the time it takes to produce that result. Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: yeah, sure.

I am using API calls to get Cryptocurrency data from multiple websites. My goal is calling the get data API with constant period ( mean of last periods). lets assume 60 requests per min. some of the websites are lazy to answer. for example assume all the responses will deliver after 10 secs . really I don't care when the response will receive( or even it may have Timeout error after 60 secs). this waiting for API response  are annoying. I just want to send requests with the same periods.

Comment: @Ario what if i wanted to do the exact same thing only having other lines of code running after run_until_complete, i'm looking for a solution which does not involve  blocking the code with run_until_complete or asyncio.run

Comment: @eranotzap, when you use async tasks, tasks should wait for their result. event_loop make an environment for them and in a some point of your code you have to wait for the event_loop itself. it means the interpreter can not go further and finish the program. so we need to think about life of the event_loop. you may have better options but I'm thinking on two ways. first make and start a new thread for running event_loop and then finish your program by your other codes. second put your other codes in a function and run it as a new task( asyncio.create_task).

Comment: @Ario i came to the same conclusion, i either block at the end of the script on the main thread or block a separate thread. this also makes sense to me because of nodejs event loop which will keep your process alive (block it from ending) if something is scheduled to run

Answer (score 10):

Instead of `await`ing the coroutine, call [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) to spawn a task object that runs in the background. At your next iteration you can check if the task is done and await/cancel it accordingly. (Otherwise asyncio will complain of un-awaited tasks being garbage collected.)

Comment: well, that's until you get an error "coroutine '***' was never awaited"

Comment: @carlo Can you give an example? I don't think you should be getting this warning if you create a task out of the coroutine, and either await or cancel it, as the answer suggests.

Comment: yeah that's true. I'm a bit struggling with asyncio as for now, because I don't like that the program/thread must keep running after the task is created, but I'm getting the hang of it now.

Comment: `create_task` does not run the task.

Comment: @bmitc The answer doesn't claim that it does, but that it "spawns" the task, i.e. arranges for it to run in the background. The actual running is done by asyncio, assuming the event loop is active, as is the case in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is using the `run_until_complete(main())` which does not satisfy your concurrency purpose. So, assuming your coroutine tasks (`do_something()`) are bounded to `5`, your code will be as follows:

```
import time
from random import randint

period = 1  # Second

def get_epoch_ms():
    return int(time.time() * 1000.0)

async def do_something(name):
    print("Start  :", name, get_epoch_ms())
    try:
        # Do something which may takes more than 1 secs.
        slp = randint(1, 5)
        print("Sleep  :", name, get_epoch_ms(), slp)
        await asyncio.sleep(slp)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error  :", e)

    print("Finish :", name, get_epoch_ms())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
futures = [loop.create_task(do_something('T' + str(i)))
           for i in range(5)]

loop.run_forever()

for f in futures:
    f.cancel()
```

Here is the concurrency workflow in its output:

```
Start  : T0 1558937750705
Sleep  : T0 1558937750705 5
Start  : T1 1558937750705
Sleep  : T1 1558937750705 1
Start  : T2 1558937750705
Sleep  : T2 1558937750705 4
Start  : T3 1558937750705
Sleep  : T3 1558937750705 5
Start  : T4 1558937750705
Sleep  : T4 1558937750705 5
Finish : T1 1558937751707
Finish : T2 1558937754709
Finish : T0 1558937755707
Finish : T3 1558937755708
Finish : T4 1558937755708
```

---

However, If your coroutine tasks are not bounded you could do it:

```
...
async def main(loop):
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        loop.create_task(do_something('T' + str(i)))
        await asyncio.sleep(period)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Comment: loop.run_forever() never yields execution back to the python interpreter 
so all though the task run in the background the code blocks, how can i runs a task which uses async await without having to block the initiating code ?

Comment: @eranotzap in the above example I used `run_forever()`, however the tasks are bounded

Comment: run_forever blocks the executing thread, i'm looking for a way to send a task to the event loop without blocking execution

Comment: @eranotzap yes, because asyncio tasks are being run in a single thread. So if you really want something that not to be blocking you most likely need the combination of threading and asyncio. I mean call the asyncio runner in a sub-thread.

Comment: that's not what i meant, i know it's a single thread on the single event loop it just that starting the event loop blocks from main thread blocks the main thread. 
what i ended up doing is running the calling run_forever at the very end of my script